# Unable to connect the html files with angular

Tags: html, angularjs, web

`I am new to angular and unable to get the output of Json File.
This is the link to code https://github.com/sumitpatel93/http_service

I get output as

Names and ages of the customers in area:
{{ person.Name + ' : ' + person.age }}

when I run my html file

code :jsfiddle.net/sumit93/5731fLm1/

Comment: any error messages ?

Comment: inside success print `console.log(response)`

Comment: @Lorenzo : I just get this ,when I run my html file                               Names and ages of the customers in area:                                               {{ person.Name + ' : ' + person.age }}

Comment: Post your code here in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the following steps to resolve this bug:

```
$http.get('file:///home/sumit/Desktop/angularjs%20Apps/http%20service/database.json');
```

1. Replace the above line with following one in controller.js

`$http.get('database.json')`

2. Add `}` at the end of database.json file
3. Replace `person.age` with `person.Age` in http_service.html

Comment: Thanks for the help .I have done the edits 1 and 3 but unable to understand the 2nd edit ? still not getting the output

Comment: your json file contain wrong json format you need to place "}" at the end of file. and please accept the answer if you found your solution

Comment: Thanks for the help,this is the correct format.$http.get("/home/sumit/Desktop/angularjs Apps/http service/database.json").then(function (response)